# Automate ls command after every cd command in tcsh

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

I change the directory by giving `cd (dir_path)`. When I give this, it also wants to display the contents in the directory. Say like if we type `ls` after going to that directory. Basically the two commands should execute together `cd (dir_path)` and a `ls` in that path only by giving the `cd (dir_path)` command.

How to do that in `tcsh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simpliest method is to use `cwdcmd`:

```
alias cwdcmd ls
```

Can be put it into `~/.tcshrc`.

See [man tcsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh):

> Special aliases
>
> ....
>
> cwdcmd
>
> Runs after every change of working directory.

Answer (score 3):

According to [uzsolt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934599/uzsolt)'s comment this answer doesn't apply to `tcsh`. The original question did not name this requirement. The question was edited later after the OP mentioned `tcsh` in a comment.

See [uzsolt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57594051/10622916) for a solution that works with `tcsh`. This answer should be upvoted.

In `bash` or `zsh` you can define a function named `cd`

```
cd ()
{
  command cd "$@" && ls
}
```

When you then run `cd somedir` you will call your function `cd` instead of the command. If you want to call the normal `cd` command, use

```
command cd [somedir]
```

Or you can later remove the function using

```
unset cd
```

Or define a function of a different name and use an alias

```
cdls ()
{
  command cd "$@" && ls
}

alias cd=cdls
```

You can then use `cdls [somedir]` or `cd [somedir]`.

Again you can call

```
command cd [somedir]
```

to get the normal `cd` command.

You can also remove the alias to get the normal behavior.

```
unalias cd
```

Comment: this cdls () function should be added into tcshrc file right?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with `tcsh`. You didn't mention this in your question. A function `cdls` can be defined for every shell (including non-interactive ones), a function or an alias `cd` which replaces the normal `cd` command should be defined for an interactive shell only.

Comment: @VicKy Try if the function (and alias) work in `tcsh`. If you want to know into which startup file you should put the function or alias definition, add this to your question.

Comment: @Bodo `tcsh` doesn't support functions so your solution can't adapt to `tcsh`.

Answer (score 0):

```csh
alias cd 'cd \!* && ls && pwd'
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to execute command one after another using && operator

```
cd `directory` && ls
```

Comment: If you use an alias only, you cannot pass a command line argument to the `cd` command inside the alias. A function allows passing the command line arg.

Comment: Indeed. My bad.